# How to import Multi maven project which is built in ant in eclipse?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, ant

An old large scaled project which contains four modules of maven one being parent and other three as its child. all this structure is built on ant.

It uses Spring framework, hibernate and FTL in Gui 
how to get it running on Eclipse ?

Comment: How can a multi-module Maven project be "built on ANT"?

Answer (score 0):

- Install Eclipse plugin [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)
- import under Eclipse the root project with the wizard
  Maven > Existing Maven Project
- convert it as a Maven project
- import the modules as Maven projects